# Calabash Console Output Buffer

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

Update: This issue has been resolved. Resolution in comments below.

When running Calabash tests in both terminal or through Rubymine, the output does not display until the test is finished.  With webdriver tests, we get output in real time.  Is there a way to display console output in real time with Calabash?

Additional Details

```
>xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer

>xcodebuild -version
Xcode 5.1.1
Build version 5B1008

>calabash-ios version
0.9.169

irb(main):002:0> server_version
```

(I removed the app name)

```
{
                    "outcome" => "SUCCESS",
                     "app_id" => "com.<redacted>",
           "simulator_device" => "iPhone",
                    "version" => "0.9.169",
                   "app_name" => "<redacted>",
"iphone_app_emulated_on_ipad" => false,
                      "4inch" => true,
                        "git" => {
    "remote_origin" => "git@github.com:calabash/calabash-ios-server.git",
           "branch" => "master",
         "revision" => "ca62f6e"
},
                "app_version" => "1.0",
                "iOS_version" => "7.1",
                     "system" => "x86_64",
                  "simulator" => "iPhone Simulator 463.9.41, iPhone OS 7.1 (iPhone Retina (4-inch)/11D167)"
}
```

Comment: We need more details. Please see this calabash-ios topic - http://goo.gl/yQi0bE - and update your question.  I have never seen this happen in the shell or in RubyMine.  Does this always happen? Or does it happen only sometimes?

Comment: Doh! I even read that post.  Added the details, and yes, this happens every time in both the shell and in rubymine.

Comment: Also, we are running calabash in Rake tasks.

Comment: Can we see the exact command that is run?  As in, can you post the rake task?  In the meantime, can you try using the slowhandcuke formatter.  `$ cucumber -f 'Slowhandcuke::Formatter'` to see if it makes a difference.  As a sanity check, I work with clients who use rake tasks to run cucumber - they do not have this issue.

Comment: The following is what Rubymine kicks off the tests with:

`/Users/<redacted>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/<redacted>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/rake features:ios:default`

I run in console by exporting all my environment variables and then merely running:

`rake features:ios:default`

Comment: I am afraid that we will need to see the _actual_ cucumber command that is executed with all the arguments.

Comment: Here ya go:
cucumber  -r features --guess --color --verbose  --exclude \.html --exclude \.htm --exclude \.yml --exclude \.jpg --exclude \.JPG --exclude \.tif --exclude \.bmp --exclude \.png --exclude \.doc --exclude \.docx --exclude \.xls --exclude \.xml --exclude \.pdf --exclude \.txt --exclude \.dot --exclude \.bat --exclude \.PNG --exclude \.mdb --exclude \.zip --exclude \.gem --exclude \.apk --exclude \.jar  --exclude load_android.rb  --format html --out output/development/ios-2014-07-07_15-23-37.html --tags @tuggles

Comment: I just realized we are having this issue beyond calabash. I appreciate your help.  I'll start looking elsewhere for answers.

Comment: Ok, we fixed the issue.  The problem was that we were using backticks to call cucumber.  After replacing the backticks with: "system(bundle exec cucumber #{params})", the output comes through fine.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario I have seen where Calabash stops displaying test output logs is , if user specifies any of the output format while running the tests. For e.g
--format json -out cucumber.json
--format html -out TestReport.html
Also, if you can specify how are you running the Tests and what your project structure looks like, may be I can help you better.

Comment: I routinely use multiple formatters and have never seen this behavior.  Any chance you are using slowhandcuke?  @Bharat can you post how you are running cucumber?

Comment: @jmoody - I don't see the logs if I run my tests in the following way DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://deviceip:37265 BUNDLE_ID=com.test.app cucumber --format json -out cucumber.json --tags testtag(for eg .@login)

Comment: I think it is because you have not specified a terminal-based formatter.  Add this as a formatter:  `-f 'Slowhandcuke::Formatter'`.  If slowhandcuke is not to your liking use:  `-f pretty`.